# increase rhandsontable checkbox size

Tags: r, rhandsontable

Does any one have an idea how to increase the size of the checkbox itself in a cell ? I have been able to increase the size of the row and of the columns, but it turns out that increasing the row and column size does not increase the size of the checkbox inside the cell

Thanks